# PHP file upload on registration

Tags: php, html, opencart

I have been working on a registration form for opencart for a while now. I think I am nearly there in how I have coded it.

However I just do not know where I am going wrong with it.

It is a standard form with text input fields and I just now need a file to be uploaded also on registration. I have added the upload button and added controller code just not working.

This is what I have so far:

Template file:

```
    <legend>Documents</legend>
<p>Please upload as .pdf to ensure a smooth upload, thank you.</p>
<div class="form-group required">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-ast">AST:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="file" name="ast" value="<?php echo "AST"; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_ast; ?>" id="input-ast" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
```

Controller:

```
    $data['ast'] = '';
$uploads_dir = 'tenant/upload/'; // set you upload path here
if (is_uploaded_file($this->request->files['ast']['tmp_name'])) {

    move_uploaded_file($this->request->files['ast']['tmp_name'],$uploads_dir.$this->request->files['ast']['name']);
  $data['ast'] = $this->request->files['ast']['name'];
}
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Put the code in the question,nobody will download files to debug code for you

Comment: @Mihai thanks for the tip i shall do that now

Comment: May be you're missing this `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag?

Comment: @dchayka thanks for commenting sadley the enctype is correct

Comment: @stephenaxe18 if you place something like a `die()` statement inside the IF statement, will it work? Meaning does the file even upload to tmp folder.

Comment: @dchayka - just tried it as still is not uploading to the folder or submitting the patch to the database

Comment: @dchayka - it doesnt seam to do anything doesnt upload to the folder and doesnt post the path in the db, just so confused with it

Comment: @stephenaxe18 can you update your question and post entire form tag code as well as form/action processing file.